# Why is my program being marked as wrong answer in vjudge.net, alhough my output is the same?

Tags: java

This is the question:
https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/100/10082.pdf
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {



    public static void main (String [] abc) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        String b="QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,./";
        String result="";
        String input=sc.nextLine();
        String uppercase=input.toUpperCase();
        for(int i=0;i<uppercase.length();i++)
        {
            try
            {
            for(int c=0;c<b.length();c++)
            {

          if(uppercase.charAt(i)==b.charAt(c))
            {
                result=result+b.charAt(c-1);
                break;
            }
            else if(Character.isWhitespace(uppercase.charAt(i))==true)
            {
                result=result+ " ";
                break;
            }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

I don't know what is wrong about this code. The output is the same as the output in the question

Comment: Please indent according to the nesting structure. Otherwise, your code is hard to read.

Comment: How is it judged? is there some way of doing it you have to use?

Comment: How should we know? We are not the ones who wrote the test cases.

Comment: not sure about digits, and are you sure ` ]` is to the *left* of `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what is missing,

You havent done it all, Look at the information in the pdf.

> Input consists of several lines of text. Each line may contain digits,
>   spaces, upper case letters (exceptQ,A,Z), or punctuation shown above
>   [except back-quote (`)]. Keys labelled with words [Tab,BackSp,Control,
>   etc.] are not represented in the input

What in that information are you NOT dealing with.... where are the **DIGITS**

Comment: but also "**Output**
You are to replace each letter or punction symbol by the one immediately to its left ..." har dto say

Comment: The testing will obviously randomly test, and it should support digits which you do not support in the code you listed, so if it put in the string 2wsx it should return 1qaz but its not as 1 doesnt exist.